# Sequence não está sendo preenchida usando chave composta ( @Embeddable )

Tags: java, jpa, spring-jpa

Estou tendo problema ao fazer a persistência da tabela abaixo, a mesma está mapeada com chave compostas, ao fazer a persistência não está gravando o valor da sequence.

Alguem consegue dar um dica?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ICONES")
public class PRIcone implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @EmbeddedId
  private PRIconePk pk = new PRIconePk();

  @Column(name = "ativo")
  private Boolean ativo;

}

@Embeddable
public class PRIconePk implements Serializable {

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PR_ICONES")
  @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "PR_ICONES", sequenceName = "SEQ_ICONE")
  @Column(name = "COD")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "item_cod")
  private Long itemCod;

}
```

meu service está da seguinte forma:

```
      PRIconeBuilder pr = PRIcone.builder().ativo(Boolean.TRUE);
      return repository.save(pr.build());
```